# What does "encrypt all outgoing email" really mean?

Tags: email, 4.3-jelly-bean, encryption

I have a Samsung Galaxy Stardust with Android 4.3.  In the email app, under security options, there is an option that says "encrypt all outgoing email".  But my understanding of S/MIME is that in order to encrypt e-mail to someone, I have to have their public key.  So it seems like this option can't really do what it says it does.

Comment: It likely means to use SMTPS, not S/MIME or S/GPG.

Comment: @LieRyan, when you set up a mail account, there are settings for communicating with the mail server with SSL, so if "encrypt all outgoing email" meant the same thing, that would be redundant.

Answer (score -1):

It actually gets the public key of the receiver before sending the email. So yes, it could do what it says.

Comment: Gets the public key how?  Unless that person has already sent me a signed message, I don't see how it would be able to get the public key.